# useContext returns the default value not the expected value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I press the submit button in the consumer I'm getting "default block" not "useModal"

I think I'm doing everything as demonstrated by all tutorials and guides on the internet, but no matter what I try it always return the default value not the expected value

Component with context creation

```
const ShowModalStateContext = React.createContext(false);
const ShowModalFnContext = React.createContext(() => {
  console.log("default block");
});

export const useModal = () => {
  console.log("useModal");
  return useContext(ShowModalFnContext);
};

const ModalWrapper: React.FC<ModalWrapperProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  function showModalFn() {
    console.log("hideModal");
    setShowModal(true);
  }

  return (
    <ShowModalStateContext.Provider value={showModal}>
      <ShowModalFnContext.Provider value={showModalFn}>
        <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
          {showModal && (
            <div
              style={{
                 ...
              }}
            >
              <div
                style={{
                  ....
                }}
              >
                {/* Your form components and content go here */}
                <form>
                  <label>
                    User Name:
                    <input type="text" />
                  </label>
                  {/* Additional form fields go here */}
                  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    setShowModal(false);
                  }}
                >
                  Close
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
          {children}
        </div>
      </ShowModalFnContext.Provider>
    </ShowModalStateContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ModalWrapper;
```

Consumer:

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const showModal = useModal();

  return (
    <ModalWrapper
      <div className="card">
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setCount(count + 1);
            showModal();
          }}
        >
          count is {count}
        </button>
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to test HMR
        </p>
      </div>
      <p className="read-the-docs">
        Click on the Vite and React logos to learn more
      </p>
    </ModalWrapper>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried logging there and checking existing questions but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem here is that I'm using the `useModal` in a space that's considered parent think of it like this:

```
<App>
   <ModalWrapper>
     ...
   </ModalWrapper>
</App>
```

The fix was moving all the code inside into another component that's wrapped with my wrapper

```
const Application: React.FC = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const showModal = useModal();

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="card">
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setCount(count + 1);
            showModal();
          }}
        >
          count is {count}
        </button>
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to test HMR
        </p>
      </div>
      <p className="read-the-docs">
        Click on the Vite and React logos to learn more
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <ModalWrapper>
      <Application />
    </ModalWrapper>
  );
}

export default App;
```